# A unique Java and Javascript intertwining act

Tags: java, javascript

I have a java program that processes information, but I want to make it so the end user can write javascripts that dictate what to do with this info. Like this

```
 //Java
 private void newData(int var1) {
     script.newData(var1);
 }
```

and then

```
 //Javascript
 function newData(var var1) {
     someVar = var1;
     processVar();
 }
```

I have looked into something called rhino, but I really am having trouble understanding the concept of rhino. Anyone know what to do?

Comment: I'm not real familiar with it, but [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) might help. Be careful of security issues, though.

Comment: Read up on the Java scripting environment; Rhino is easy to integrate, and standard in JSE 6+.

Comment: You don't declare variable types in javascript `(var var1)` should be just `(var1)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Isn't that for web apps?

Comment: @DaveNewton - I'm not real familiar with it, but from what I understand, you can use it to build Javascript functionality using Java. Or something.

Comment: @JaredFarrish But... but the OP is specifically asking about using JavaScript to script their Java app, a capability provided out-of-the-box as of Java 6. GWT is a web framework for writing client (browser) code in Java, which is compiled to JavaScript, and run in the browser.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Ok. What it sounds like to me is that Java app is going to provide underlying data and that the user will then make JS that works on that server-supplied data. But you could be right. This discussion is going nowhere. I've registered that you think the suggestion is not accurate, so we can let it go now. `:)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish So you are saying, I should go with trying my luck embedding rhino... Okay

Comment: @JaredFarrish I believe you understand correctly, except for the GWT part.

Comment: Rhino seems appropriate. I've only heard of it, though, and glanced at their homepage just now. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). Rhino is a javascript runtime implemented in Java. It is suitable for embedding in Java applications.

What you want to do is create your Java classes and objects and then make them accessible to a Javascript environment. Fortunately this is very easy with Rhino. Read [this tutorial](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/tutorial.html) and pay close attention to the first and second sections (*RunScript: A simple embedding* and *Expose Java APIs*).

The first section is about executing Javascript within a Java application. You will need to adapt their sample code a little to provide some way for the end user to hand javascript code to you (in a file or stream) for you to execute. It won't be difficult.

The second section is about making your Java stuff available to the Javascript stuff. In the simplest case you don't need to do *anything*--all of Java is available to Rhino javascript automatically. But you can very easily pretty up the interface and provide something easier for the end user to use if you want.

With Rhino you can also go in the other direction--you can make Javascript objects available to the Java environment. This is a little more complicated, but is covered in the rest of the tutorial. You may not need to do this either.